# Difficulty applying a Regex to a Rails View. Should I make it a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to apply the following regex to one of my views:

```regex
^([^\s]+)\s+
```

This is to remove any string of consecutive non-whitespace characters including any white space characters that follow from the start of the line (remove everything except the first word). I have input it on Rubular and it works.
[image: Rubular test]

I was wondering how I would be able to apply it to my rails project. Would I create a rails helper method? So far I have tested it in irb and it is not returning the right value:
[image: irb Test]

I would like to know how I can fix my method and if making it a helper method is the right approach. Thank you very much for your help guys!

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The =~ operator matches the regular expression against a string, and it returns either the offset of the match from the string if it is found, otherwise nil.

You could either try it with `String.match` and work with the match data.
like

```rb
str.match(^([^\s]+)\s+)
```

or you don't use regex for readability. Split the string on spaces and return and array of the words and take the first one, like:

```rb
str.split(' ').first
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Denny!  I opted for the second one. Do you know by any chance what the rule of thumb is for using helper methods?

Comment: Use a helper to remove logic from your view, and in particular if you'll reuse the same method in multiple places. It helps keep views tidier and keeps your code DRY.

Comment: Thank you @JohnP for the feedback! Actually keeping code tidy is a thing I am struggling with 

Comment: Heh - I think we all struggle with that to some degree! Generally, if you're doing anything more complex in your view than "if @variable.present? [SOME HTML] else [DIFFERENT HTML] end", you should probably be using a helper function. (And, even then, you'll often see helpers that take a variable and return the relevant HTML fragment, so the view just has a helper call!) If you're doing something moderately complex, you may even be better using your own custom ruby objects!

Comment: Hey @JuanC ... @JohnP already gave a nice comment to it which I also agree on. Rule of thumb would be: `If you use or will use it multiple times make it a method`

Comment: Thank you guys for the input, I really appreciate it!